# Auto update php method documentation in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In php methods grow in size, as do the quantity of params required.

Is it possible to get PhpStorm to auto-update the previously generated PHPDoc above the said methods, instead of manually writing the additions/subtractions...?

Comment: Nope -- no automatic updates without user consent. But you can place caret in such PHPDoc comment (or, better, on additional parameters), press `Alt+Enter` (or via light bulb icon) and choose appropriate quick fix method there. This will work if appropriate inspection is enabled in PhpStorm settings (`Editor | Inspections` -- look for PHPDoc section)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope -- no automatic updates without user consent.

[Similar kind of request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27952#comment=27-1039297) -- check the dev's comment.

---

You can place caret in such PHPDoc comment (or, better, on such new/additional parameters), press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> (or via light bulb icon) and choose appropriate quick fix entry there.

This will work if appropriate inspection is enabled (should be by default) in PhpStorm settings (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP`) -- look for PHPDoc section (hint: also try search box).

Comment: alt + enter = very nice ;)

Comment: Thanks, option + enter on mac